# Celery не видит tasks

Tags: python, celery

Я использую Celery Redis и Django
Когда я запускаю

```
    celery -A proj worker -beat
```

у меня запускается celery, но он не видит tasks

```
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
 - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

settings:

```
# адрес redis сервера
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
# храним результаты выполнения задач так же в redis
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
# в течение какого срока храним результаты, после чего они удаляются
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 7*86400  # 7 days
# это нужно для мониторинга наших воркеров
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
# место хранения периодических задач (данные для планировщика)
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task': 'app.tasks.run',
    'schedule': 10,  # в секундах, или timedelta(seconds=10)

}
# в конец settings.py добавляем строчки
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

tasks

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery.task import task
from proj.celery import app


@app.task()
def run():
    print("Print from celery task")
```

celery

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from datetime import timedelta

from django.conf import settings


#@periodic_task(run_every = timedelta(seconds = 60))
#def run():
#    print("is works!")


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send-report-every-single-minute': {
        'task': "app.tasks.run",
        'schedule': 5,
    },
}
```

**init**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Comment: Ваш файл tasks.py точно находится в том приложении, которое прописано в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: да находится именно в этом приложении

Comment: Возможно не уместно будет но а если запустить worker и beat по отдельности?

Answer (score 0):

Текущая стока:
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

Замени на:
app.autodiscover_tasks()

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).